# Anyway to make OpenVPN's DNS entry the last priority?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

I'm connecting from school to home.  I have OpenVPN set so that only home network connections go through the VPN; it is NOT set to send all traffic through the VPN.  And I would prefer to keep it that way.  As it is, I have the server set to push my home network's local DNS server to the client.

The problem is - the school has some local resources that have a different internal IP than internet-facing IP.  But when I connect to my OpenVPN, it gets the IP of the internet-facing address, but then since it is not on my home network it tries to connect through the schools network and fails (no NAT-redirection apparently).

Is there any way to set the DNS server pushed by OpenVPN to be the last priority in DNS resolution so it tries the school's DNS servers first?  It doesn't matter if it has to be configured on the OpenVPN server or the client config.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prioritize adapters for DNS resolution, check [this ServerFault question and its answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/21455/how-to-configure-dns-on-windows-with-multiple-nics) (the only difference is that one of your adapters is virtual).

Alternatively, if the resources within your school have a FQDN, you can set an appropriate [DNS suffix settings on your interface](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816716(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, setting the adapter priority did it.  The OpenVPN adapter was the top priority; I moved it to the bottom and now I can access both the school internal webpages and my home network - so far no problem.